# error in strsplit when trying to separate by a comma

Tags: r, strsplit

I have the vector

```
length
# [1] 15,34, 12,24, 225,
# Levels: 12,24, 15,34, 225,
```

and I want to separate them by the comma to eventually make a list of these values

Tried:

```
strsplit(length, ",")
```

but keep getting the error message

```
Error in strsplit(length, ",") : non-character argument
```

Answer (score 11):

Your "length" object is a `factor`:

As the error message indicates, `strsplit` expects a character vector as the input.

Try:

```
strsplit(as.character(length), ",")
```

#### Demo

```
x <- factor(c("1,2", "3,4", "5,6"))
strsplit(x, ",")
# Error in strsplit(x, ",") : non-character argument
strsplit(as.character(x), ",")
# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "3" "4"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "5" "6"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use: (`x` from @Ananda Mahto's post)

```
 library(stringr)
 str_split(x, ",")
 #[[1]]
 # [1] "1" "2"

 #[[2]]
 #[1] "3" "4"

 #[[3]]
 #[1] "5" "6"
```

Or

```
  str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]+")
```

Or

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_extract_all_regex(x, "[0-9]+")
```